# Don't set SelectedItem for Combobox in wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, combobox

I have a combobox and bind ItemsSource and SelectedItem

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"  ItemsSource="{Binding OrganizationalPostCollection,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  SelectedItem="{Binding OrganizationalPost,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="230" Margin="5" />
```

and in ViewModel

```
OrganizationalPost _organizationalPost;
public OrganizationalPost OrganizationalPost
{
    get { return _organizationalPost; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _organizationalPost)
        {
            _organizationalPost = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("OrganizationalPost");
        }
    }
}

ICollectionView _organizationalPostCollection;
public ICollectionView OrganizationalPostCollection
{
    get { return _organizationalPostCollection; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _organizationalPostCollection)
        {
            _organizationalPostCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("OrganizationalPostCollection");
        }
    }
}
```

and in Constructor

```
OrganizationalPostCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(db.OrganizationalPost.ToList());
OrganizationalPost = SelectedUser.OrganizationalPost;
```

OrganizationalPost  have value, but don't set in SelectedItem.

Comment: where does `SelectedUser.OrganizationalPost` come from is it a reference to a `OrganizationalPost`item in the `OrganizationalPostCollection` or is it from somwhere else?

Comment: It is from some where else.

Comment: Try to set the object type in ICollectionView (i.e ICollection<OrganizationalPost>)

Comment: One of the possible reason is that the hash id of the selected object (SelectedUser.OrganizationalPost) does not match with any item within (OrganizationalPostCollection). You need to ensure that the selected item matches exactly one of the item in ItemsSource

Comment: @Daniel : I use `ICollection<OrganizationalPost>` but don't work :(

Comment: @bjoshi : No, SelectedUser.OrganizationalPost is in OrganizationalPostCollection. I use `OrganizationalPost = db.OrganizationalPost.Find(SelectedUser.OrganizationalPost.Id)` it is work !!!!

Comment: @ar.gorgin that is the point that means they are different reference i.e. SelectedUser.OrganizationalPost's has id is different i.e. a different reference i.e. created and not present in the list. there is a similar item in list i.e. with same id and same members but the address is different

Answer (score 4):

In order to select a value for the `SelectedItem` property and have the UI update, the item that you set *must* be from the collection that is set as the `ItemsSource` for the same control:

```
OrganizationalPost = OrganizationalPostCollection[selectedItemIndex];
```

or if your class has a uniquely identifiable property:

```
OrganizationalPost = OrganizationalPostCollection.Where(p => p.Id == itemToSelect.Id).
Single();
```